# Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service discovery.Discovery Using Hyperledger Fabric Node sdk Service Discovery

Tags: javascript, hyperledger-fabric

I am trying to use the service discovery by bootstrapping (providing anchor peer) following this documentation: https://fabric-sdk-node.github.io/tutorial-discovery.html. Below is where the error is.

controller.js `Error: 12 UNIMPLEMENTED: unknown service discovery.Discovery` (I have tried different permutations of the channel.initialize method).

```
            let fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();
            let channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');
            let peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpc://localhost:7051');
            channel.addPeer(peer);
            try {
                let discovery_response = await channel.initialize({
                    discover: true, 
                    target: peer,
                    asLocalhost: true
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('discovery response: ', error || discovery_response);
            }
```

I have also added the gossip protocol to the peer docker environment. Also I already able to submit transactions and use the node sdk with no issues except for the service discovery.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to upgrade the network peers to version 1.2 
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrading_your_network_tutorial.html